# The side menu button in navigation drawer is not working when i press it in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    headerLeft: (
      <View style ={{padding:10}}>
        <Ionicons name = "md-menu" size={32} onPress ={()=>{navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of react-navigation are you using. React navigation (v2) or v1

Comment: React navigation version2

Answer (score 3):

As by React Navigation(v2). you may find the documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

you need to use like this below

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: <Button onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
})
```

**To open and close drawer, use the following helpers to open and close the drawer:**

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
```

**If you would like to toggle the drawer you call the following:**

```
this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
```

**Each of these functions, behind the scenes, are simply dispatching actions:**

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

Comment: this did not work. the menu opens and closes by itself :(
type
Navigation/TOGGLE_DRAWER
key
undefined

Comment: You can set the header for your stack navigator while setting up your navigators itself or You need to declare the **static navigationOptions** in your stack navigator's component itself.  Kindly follow up with this link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html for reference

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue of navigation for me.

1. Install NativeBase by running `npm install --save native-base`
2. Run `react-native link` to link the fonts
3. Import this `import {Header, Left, Icon} from 'native-base'`
4. The add this code to `render(){}`

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <View>
         <Header>
           <Left>
             <Icon name="menu" style={{ color: 'white'}} 
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
           </Left>
         </Header>
         <View>
           <Text>Home Contents</Text>
         </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
   ```